# Make two functions have the same memory address in C++

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I am building some shared libraries to test different algorithms.
The header of all shared libraries should look like this:

```
extern "C" {
  void f1(params);
  void f2(params);
}
```

where both functions have exactly the same parameters.

In one of the implementations, I realized that I would need need to have `f1 == f2`, but I want them to share the same memory space.

Is there a way to do that? I know that function pointers usually do the trick, but this time I need to follow the shared library standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's platform specific.  For GCC, you can do this:

```
extern "C" {
  void f1(params);
  void f2(params) __attribute__((weak, alias("f1")));
}
```

Ref: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes

Comment: Seems to be nice, but I am not able to touch the header. Is it possible to do something similar in the definition?

Comment: @RGAM: I think you can leave the header as it is, then just put the f2() line I wrote with the attribute in your implementation file.